# JUnit Failure when testing

Tags: java, arrays, junit, junit4

For one of my exercises, I have to test my work with JUnit. The first test passed with no errors but the other two have no errors but have failures instead.
What does this mean?

```
public class TestExercise2 {

int [][] numArray = {{3, -1,  4,  0},{5,  9, -2,  6},{5,  3,  7, -8}}; 

@Test
public void sumOfRows() {

    assertEquals(31, Exercise2.sum(numArray));
}

@Test
public void rowsSums() {

    int [] i = new int [] {6, 18, 7};
    assertArrayEquals(i, Exercise2.rowsSums(numArray));
}

@Test
public void columnSums() {

    int [] i = new int [] {13,11,9,-2};
    assertArrayEquals(i, Exercise2.columnSums(numArray));
}
```

Comment: That your assertions are not valid. Either an error in your code(the methods you call) or in your test cases.

Comment: This may mean that your unit test is working and columSums and rowsSums methods are improperly implemented. Past code for this methods.

Answer (score 4):

This means that the method the methods being tested in other two test cases are not returning the result as per your expectation and `assertArrayEquals` method checks your expectation for you. Refer to the [documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your assertions are totally fine and legal, you just need to make sure you're comparing two comparable arrays. I believe the problem is in retrieving wrongly created arrays from `Exercise2`'s methods `rowsSums()` and `columnSums()`. So I attempted to create those and couple of helping methods such as `getRows()` 
and `getColumns()`.

> Now all tests will pass!

```
public class Exercise2 {

public static int getRows(int[][] numArray) {
    // if there are no rows, method will simply return 0
    return numArray.length;
}

public static int getColumns(int[][] numArray) {
    // if there are no rows,
    // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown
    // so need to check
    if (getRows(numArray) != 0)
        return numArray[0].length;
    return 0;
}

public static int[] rowsSums(int[][] numArray) {
    // getRows(numArray) will return 3
    int[] rowsSums = new int[getRows(numArray)];
    int sum = 0;
    // iterating over an array
    for (int i = 0; i < getRows(numArray); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getColumns(numArray); j++) {
            sum += numArray[i][j];
        }
        // when row is finished,
        // store sum as [i] element of an array
        rowsSums[i] = sum;
        // setting sum to zero before iterating over next row
        sum = 0;
    }
    return rowsSums;
}

public static int[] columnSums(int[][] numArray) {
    // getColumns(numArray) will return 4
    int[] columnSums = new int[getColumns(numArray)];
    int sum = 0;
    // now we iterate over columns first
    // so i < getColumns()
    for (int i = 0; i < getColumns(numArray); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getRows(numArray); j++) {
            // swapped i and j
            sum += numArray[j][i];
        }
        // same thing as before
        columnSums[i] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
    return columnSums;
}
}
```

---

You can also add a `sizesOfArray()` test to verify correctness of calculations.

```
@Test
public void sizesOfArray() {
    assertEquals(3, Exercise2.getRows(numArray));
    assertEquals(4, Exercise2.getColumns(numArray));

    // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will not be thrown
    assertEquals(0, Exercise2.getRows(new int[0][0]));
    assertEquals(0, Exercise2.getColumns(new int[0][0]));
}
```

---

Comment: Will returning Null cause JUnit to fail?

Comment: @Leon185 yes, tests will fail. But there is no chance for those methods to return null, unless you change them.

Comment: @Leon185 okay, I’ll check it

Comment: @Leon185 you're returning nothing else like null and before that you're just printing out result of calculations. You need to return array filled with resulst, like I did in my answer.

Comment: If I return the ColumnSums or RowSums it highlights it in red.

Comment: @Leon185 give me your full project code I'll fix it

Comment: @m-demianchuk Am I still able to message you the code?